# Problem by evaluating mail sending via javax mail

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

I use javax.mail for mail sending in my application. So I want to evaluate which mail sending was success at which not, if I use multiple mail addresses, anyway if for TO, CC or BCC.

I tried to evaluate this so if it throws an exception:

```
private void setTnsMailReceiverStatus(MessagingException e, List<TnsMailReceiver> receivers) {
    Exception nextException = e.getNextException();
    while (nextException != null) {
        if (nextException instanceof SendFailedException) {
            SendFailedException sendFailedException = (SendFailedException) nextException;
            this.setMailStatus(sendFailedException.getInvalidAddresses(), receivers, TnsMailStatus.ERROR);
            this.setMailStatus(sendFailedException.getValidUnsentAddresses(), receivers, TnsMailStatus.UNSENT);
        }

        nextException = e.getNextException();
    }
}
```

I tried to loop over each exception and I thought if no exception more there, getNextException will return null, but it gives me always an exception back. The functions getInvalidAddresses and getValidUnsentAddresses returns always null.

So my question is, how to handle this exception, and which is the smartest way to evaluate which mails are sent and which not? I'm new at this framework/libary.

Thank you :)

Comment: These days SMTP-servers don't tell these kind of things due to spammers.

Comment: How to tell the user then which mail had success and which not?

Comment: Yes. Basically you are not told and it is asynchronous too

Comment: The [JavaMail FAQ](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#badaddr) has some more information.